# Create a 100 percent stacked line chart with chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts

I'm using chart.js to build my charts, but felt the need to create a stacked chart inline, but using the *stacked:true* property doesn't seem to work

Here is my code

```
var chart1 = new Chart(document.getElementById("invests2").getContext("2d"), {
    type: "line",
    options: {
        layout: {
            padding: 0
        },
        elements: {
            point:{
                radius: 0
            },
        },
        responsive: true,
        bezierCurve: false,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
         scales: {
             yAxes: [{
                 stacked:true,
                 display: true,
                 scaleLabel: {
                     display: true,
                 },
                 ticks: {
                     maxTicksLimit:100,
                     fontSize:12,
                     maxRotation: 0,
                     minRotation: 0
                 },
                 gridLines: {
                     display: false,
                 }
             }]
         }
    },
    data: {
        labels: ['01/04/2018','01/05/2018','01/06/2018','01/07/2018','01/08/2018','01/09/2018'],
        datasets: [{
                type: 'line',
                label: 'Tit. Publicos',
                data: [20940429854.44,19639459015.81,19191914837.46,19290826114.34,19702912802,21274400792.07]
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                label: 'Tit. Privados',
                data: [315734585.11,332328878.86,349823178.63,343130519.19,342839692.62,367877901.82,]
            }
        ]
    },
});
```

The look presented was this

[image]

But i need this

[image]

Stacked:true not work for line chart?